# How do I go about removing the elevation from SliverPersistentHeader?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hopefully a simple question, I have SliverPersistentHeader inside a CustomScrollView, and it looks like this SliverPersistentHeader has some sort of shadow/elevation. Is there a way to remove it (I've outlined the shadow in the red box)?

See picture below:
[image]

This basic body is a scaffold with the SliverPersistentHeader coming from the _makeHeader call:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Consts.coMainBackground,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          _sliverAppBar(),
          _makeHeader(),
          BlocBuilder<AllPersonsBloc, AllPersonsState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is AllPersonsLoading) {
                return _buildLoading();
              } else if (state is AllPersonsLoaded) {
                return _sliverList(context, state.persons);
              } else if (state is AllPersonsError) {
                return _buildErrorMessage(state.message);
              } else {
                return _buildErrorMessage('Unknown error!');
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

the Make Header function:

```
  Widget _makeHeader() {
    return SliverPersistentHeader(
      pinned: true,
      delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
        minHeight: 130.0,
        maxHeight: 130.0,
        child: Container(
          color: Consts.coForestGreenBackground,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Consts.coMainBackground,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(15), topRight: Radius.circular(15))
            ),
            child: _cardHeader('People', Icons.search, 'Name')),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
```

And finally the Delegate function:

```
class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate({
    @required this.minHeight,
    @required this.maxHeight,
    @required this.child,
  });
  final double minHeight;
  final double maxHeight;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  double get minExtent => minHeight;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => math.max(maxHeight, minHeight);

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, 
      double shrinkOffset, 
      bool overlapsContent) 
  {
    return new SizedBox.expand(child: child);
  }
  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return maxHeight != oldDelegate.maxHeight ||
        minHeight != oldDelegate.minHeight ||
        child != oldDelegate.child;
  }
}
```

And card header (not actually a card)

```
 Widget _cardHeader(String titleText, IconData inputIcon, String hint) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: standardEdgePadding),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(titleText, style: Consts.cardHeaderStyle,),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            height: 40,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Consts.inputGreen,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  child: Icon(
                    inputIcon,
                    color: Consts.inputGreenText,
                    size: Consts.cardInputIconSize,
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(child: TextField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
                    hintText: hint,
                    hintStyle: Consts.cardInputStyle,
                  ),
                ),)
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out because, i have a container inside a container:

```
Widget _makeHeader() {
    return SliverPersistentHeader(
      pinned: true,
      delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
        minHeight: 130.0,
        maxHeight: 130.0,
        child: Container(
          color: Consts.coForestGreenBackground,
          child: Container(
            //There seemed to be some spacing between the search header and the rest of the list, this takes care of it
            //transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Consts.coMainBackground,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(15), topRight: Radius.circular(15))
            ),
            child: _cardHeader('People', Icons.search, 'Name')),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
```

The way that the Header "meets" the SliverList there is an very minor gap (might be related to the emulator only). So the "coForestGreenBackground" colour in the parent container is showing through in that gap. There is no actual elevation/shadow.

If I uncomment the code, then the gap (aka elevation in my original question) vanishes.

I slept very poorly last night as I couldn't stop thinking about where I made a mistake. Thanks to @drogel for confirming there is no actual shadow/elevation on the SliverPersistentHeader.

Answer (score 1):

`SliverPersistentHeader` alone does not have a shadow, therefore that `elevation` effect is not coming from your `SliverPersistentHeader`. It is not explicit from your code snippets, but I can see you have a `_cardHeader('People', Icons.search, 'Name')` method in your widget tree. I suspect it contains a `Card` widget inside the widget tree this method returns.

As seen in [the Card widget Flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html), `Card`s have a default non-zero `elevation` value, which might be casting the shadow in your case. See if there is any `Card` widget in your widget tree, and set its `elevation` parameter to zero.

Comment: no cards unfortunately! I've edited my original question to show the relevant code from _cardHeader